# Microsoft Visual Source safe Internet Database adding problem.

Tags: vss, source-control

I am trying to add VSS internet.
In options all have been set. ( Plug in > Internet, Removed SSL etc).

This will add the DataBase successfully added. And immediately after adding this again the Database adding wizard will come after this below Message box.

```
---------------------------  
Visual SourceSafe Internet
---------------------------  
Could not find the Visual SourceSafe Internet Web Service connection information for the specified database ().

Would you like to launch the Visual SourceSafe connection wizard?
---------------------------  
       Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this blog entry](http://dotnetprogrammingtipsbymuhil.blogspot.in/2010/02/could-not-find-visual-sourcesafe.html):

Visual Studio » Tools » Options » Choose Source Control and Plug-in Selection.

Switch Back to Microsoft Visual SourceSafe instead of Microsoft Visual SourceSafe (Internet);